# Backbone mouse click no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a little problem with Backbone, I'm sure there's somebody who can help me !!!

Here's my HTML :

```
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slide map">
        Map
    </div>
    <div class="slide points">
        Table
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS :

```
var SlideView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'slide map',

    events: {
        'click': 'onClick'
    },

    onClick: function() {
        console.log("event !!!");
    }
});

var slideView = new SlideView();
```

When I click on the div, the callback is not executed !!!

Comment: this'll do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002466/tying-button-onclick-even-to-backbone-view

Comment: This not solved my problem...

Comment: it should not execute. you have no mapping between view and existing nodes, dont have any template in view and dont render view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your view doesn't know about the HTML that is on the page. if you don't set the view's `el` element it's not going to bind the events to the DOM elements.

To make your example work, you could do the following. [view.setElement()](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement)

```
var slideView = new SlideView();
slideView.setElement($('div.slide.map'));
```

The `tagName` and `className` doesn't go and select those elements from the DOM, it actually creates a new element as the root of the view that in this case would be `<div class="slide map"></div>`.

But ultimately you should be setting the `el` attribute on the view prototype.

```
var SlideView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'div.slide.map',    
    events: {
        'click': 'onClick'
    },

    onClick: function() {
        console.log("event !!!");
    }
});
```

Or even better, create the view with the HTML inside it and then put a reference to it on the page.

```
var SlideView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'slide map',

    render: function(){
        // this.$el is a equiv. to $(<[tagName] class="[className]"></[tagName>);
        this.$el.html("/* HTML String to go inside the tag */");
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click': 'onClick'
    },

    onClick: function() {
        console.log("event !!!");
    }
});

var slideView = new SlideView();
slideView.render();

$('#slides').prepend(slideView.$el);
```

Comment: does slideView.$el.html() give you "Map" or just an empty string?

Comment: slideView.$el.html() give me an empty string !

Comment: See my answer, the view has created an element that looks like the other one, but it's not the same element

Comment: It's missing the element selector.

Comment: @rcarvalho Where is it missing the element selector?

Comment: events: {
        'click #here': 'onClick'
    },

Comment: @rcarvalho if you don't put a selector in it uses the view's root element. From the docs: "Omitting the selector causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (this.el)."

Comment: @CubedEye, yeah you're completely right, what i mean is that for an especific object, you need to use the selector.

Comment: @CubedEye, your example it's not wrong, but is Omitting the selector,  it only works because backbone handle that for you. But it is not wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56392/discussion-between-cubed-eye-and-rcarvalho).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, you just missed element id in your event mapping. Please try following code.

```
events: {
    'click #slides': 'onClick'
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way.For events we must specify the event, the selector and the function.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, the view isn't attached to any DOM element.